# SOS hardness of $Max-2-Lin(\mathbb{Z}_2)$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, semidefinite-programming, max-cut, sum-of-squares

Do we know of instances of $Max-2-Lin(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ which have a integrality gaps w.r.t to high degree (> 4) SOS relaxations?

---

Or if we specialize to Max-CUT do we know of graphs whose Max-CUT polynomial needs high SOS degree to be solved? (Or if we at least know of integrality gaps for it for high SOS degree)

Answer (score 3):

We don't have integrality gaps even for Max-CUT, even for degree 4. See [Barak and Steurer's notes](http://sumofsquares.org/public/lec03-1_lowerbound_maxcut.html), at the end.

You might be interested in [Lee Raghavendra Steurer '14](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.6317). They seem to be saying there can be no SDP relaxations for exact Max-CUT of size $2^{n^c}$ for some $c < 1$. I think this means there can be no SOS proof of degree $n^c$, and hence there are instances of Max-CUT requiring higher degree. I lack the expertise to be sure I'm interpreting this correctly though.

Other than this, I don't know of any lower bounds for the degree of SOS that can solve Max-CUT exactly.

Comment: Thanks! What you say is what has been my understanding. But this looks peculiarly paradoxical to me. Think about it this way : Given that Max-CUT is NP-Hard how is it possible that no one has ever seen a graph which is outside even SOS_4 (thats a pretty weak level of the hierarchy!)? Has no one just maybe scanned through all possible small graphs of say size upto 10 and found one example? Is such an in-principle simple scan actually impossibly hard to do (even by softwares?) or is it that people have done such scans and no one has found any?

Comment: You could almost certainly find a small graph where degree-4 SOS thinks the graph has a larger max cut than the true optimum by enumerating small examples like you say. This is because we shouldn't expect degree-4 SOS to solve Max-Cut exactly due to NP-hardness. However, the really interesting question is *how big* of an integrality gap can you find? Can you find instances where the true cut is 0.878 of the degree-4 SOS value (thus showing deg-4 is no stronger than deg-2)? But these instances might be large e.g. Feige-Schechtman instances would be pretty big to verify experimentally.